# Unit testing browser CommonJS modules via intern

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, intern

Writing modules that will be loaded int the browser with browserify.  I'm attempting to use the `dojo/node` plugin for unit testing the modules, but it doesn't work correctly when trying to load unit tests. Would I have to wrap modules that need unit testing (i.e., browserify them before load), or is there a workaround?

Spec:

```
define([
    'intern!object',
    'intern/chai!assert',
    'require',
    // common css selectors
    'intern/dojo/node!app/selectors'
], function (
    registerSuite,
    assert,
    require,
    SEL
) {

    registerSuite({

        name: 'Selectors Unit test',

        'it is an object': function() {
            assert.ok(typeof SEL === 'object',
                      'Selectors is an object');
        }

    });

});
```

Module:

```
module.exports = {

    FOO : { _SELF: '#someId }

};
```

Running via browser at `http://localhost/node_modules/intern/client.html?config=tests/intern`

The error given is `Uncaught Error: Cannot find the Node.js require`

Does the Dojo plugin work in a browser environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `dojo/node` will not work in a browser. As the [documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/node.html) points out,

> `dojo/node` simply accesses the native `require()` function of node, passing the plugin argument as the parameter.